# Microservices component with spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I read database table using spring batch and write the same into the files. Once the job is completed, I want to log the count and job status. Please advise could there be a microservice component be written to log this data so that i can reuse this component for any kind of batch jobs in my application. Will this be a good design?

Answer (score 0):

How/where do you want to log this data and what will you be doing with it?

I don't think there is any need to be writing a microservice for logging.  Depending on what you want to do with the log output, you could get your process to log the output to a log file then use logstash to import logs into elastic search and analyse using kibana.  You can use logstash to consolidate logs for all your processes.

It really depends on what you're trying to achieve with the log output here as to what a good solution is - please provide more information on your use case.